# Why CodeIgniter 3 become slow on localhost and works normal on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I've joined a company and they are working on a very large and legacy project, which is made on CodeIgniter 3 and PHP 5.6. Project works very well on server but when we run on localhost It takes **2 min** to load the CodeIgniter and just to render the page.

#### Issue that I have traced

1. I started debugging from **index.php** of the CodeIgniter 3
2. I found that **CodeIgniter.php** is taking time to execute.
3. In **CodeIgniter.php**, I get to know that the problem starts here:

   `require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->directory.$class.'.php');`
4. Then I further traced the file, I found as it loads Models, Libraries and etc. the execution time increases and it takes even 5 to 6 min to completely load the page.

**Please guide me why is it happening and why it is not working on localhost.**

NOTE: There is no issue in database querying. I've checked it in many ways.

Comment: prevent autoloading all your models, download js and css in your project instead of using external scripts like <script src="https://www.ajax.com/js/ajax.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Please use Codeigniters in-built Profiling and Benchmarking functionality to find the bottlenecks. Below are the links to the documentation

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html?highlight=profile
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html?highlight=profile

Also please check if the server configuration/resources (Memory/CPU) is same as local that plays important role as well.